# How to setup front end and back end on one server and on one port number?

Tags: django, vue.js, ssl, frontend, backend

The frontend and backend of the site are on the same server, on different ports: frontend in on 443, and the backend on 8443. A request is sent from the frontend to create a file from the backend (in the form of GET-requests). These requests go regularly until the file is created. But for **some people**, these requests are not returned.

The following error appears in the console:

[image: Error screenshot]

**The hypothesis is that perhaps the firewall does not allow requests to be sent to port 8443.**

Trying to just enter the web address with this port number (https://app.website.com:8443/) to the browser  by these people should return the standard Django screen, but returns:

[image: error screenshot]

Here is how the servers are configured. I additionally, just in case, made sure that any cache was deleted.

This is the front end server setup:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name website.com;
return 301 https://website.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/app.website.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/app.website.com_private_key.key;

  root /home/website/dist;

  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name app.website.com;

  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

 # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
  }
}
```

This is backend server settings:

```
server {
 listen 8443 ssl;
 server_name app.website.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/app.website.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/app.website.com_private_key.key;

 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}
 location /static/ {
  root /home/website/backend;

 }

 location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

server {
 listen 8000;
 server_name 217.160.203.14;
 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}
 location /static/ {
  root /home/website/backend;
 }


 location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to set up the Backend on port 443, but still remain within the same server (and same domain)? For example, to have the Frontend on https://app.website.com/ a backend on https://app.website.com/backend (and not on port 8443)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Not really, because I cannot obtain an SSL certificate for an IP address in my case (I am using a subdomain).

Comment: There is no mention of an SSL certificate anywhere in that question, what are you talking about? If you have read the answer to that question you'll see it talks about using "location" blocks and the "proxy_pass" directive to configure both the applications on the same port with different path prefixes.